# RestKit doesn't send second request

Tags: restkit

RestKit doesn't send second request
I have a simple application with 1 view and 2 buttons
titles of buttons are hostnames (yandex.ru and localhost:3000)
when i click on any button at first time 
request works
but if i click second time on any it doesn't send it....
what do i do wrong?

below is part of code of my ViewController

```cs
- (IBAction)testRestkit:(UIButton *)sender
{
   RKClient *client =[RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",sender.titleLabel.text]];
   client.cachePolicy = RKRequestCachePolicyNone;
   [client get:nil delegate:self];
}

- (void)requestWillPrepareForSend:(RKRequest *)request
 {
   NSLog(@"Preparing for request......");
 }

- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response
{
   if ([response isHTML]) {
     NSLog(@"Loaded html!");
   } else{
     NSLog(@"Loaded some response!"); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if i send request like code below . they works!!!! 
someone could explain difference between both methods???

```cs
- (IBAction)testRestkit:(UIButton *)sender 
{    
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",sender.titleLabel.text]]; 
   RKRequest *theRequest = [[RKRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
   theRequest.queue = [RKClient sharedClient].requestQueue;
   theRequest.delegate = self;
   [theRequest setMethod:RKRequestMethodGET];
   [theRequest send];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the first time you call `clientWithBaseURLString:`, an `[RKClient sharedClient]` singleton is initialized (and properly retained), so the subsequent call does work. When you invoke the code for the second time, the convenience constructor returns an autoreleased instance of RKClient with the another base url.

The correct way to handle multiple base URLs in RestKit is to manage two, separate instances of RKClient, e.g.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) RKClient *localhostClient;
@property (nonatomic, retain) RKClient *remoteClient;
```

and initialize them eg. in your init method (or lazily in your method).

```
static NSString *kRemoteServerUrl = @"http://yandex.ru";
- (IBAction)testRestkit:(UIButton *)sender
{
   RKClient *client = nil;
   if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:kRemoteServerUrl]) {
       if (!self.remoteClient) { 
          self.remoteClient = [RKClient clientWithBaseURLString:kRemoteServerUrl];
          client.cachePolicy = RKRequestCachePolicyNone;
       }
       [self.remoteClient get:nil delegate:self];
   } else if (.....)
....
}
```

Comment: How to manage about 20 different base hosts? I receive urls dynamically and i don't know how many url would be processed. i can't assign RKClient to different properties...

Comment: You can always keep them in a data structure such as `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`. Do you use the object mapping features of RestKit?